# given a clinic_id, how do I get the mods belonging the profile of the user

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I am really stuck here and I am considering changing my models and starting fresh

I have these models

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # Able to login
    practitioner = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # has access to a clinc
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # superuser
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # staff
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Modalities(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                related_name='prof_user',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    mods = models.ManyToManyField(Modalities)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    clinics = models.ManyToManyField(Clinic)
    personnummer = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    consent = models.BooleanField()


class Clinic(models.Model):
    practitioner = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                        related_name='prac_user',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lat = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    lng = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, )
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=128, )
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128, )
```

From my view I am trying to get the mods from the Profile model, starting with the clinic_id

something like

```
clinic = Clinic.objects.filter(pk=clinic_id)
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
mods = profile.mods
```

I have tried so many things over the last few hours and I just can't figure this out.

Do I need to change my models or am I going about accessing this wrong?

Comment: Do you seeing an error? Fist thing is that `clinic` is actually a queryset, not a single record. Another thing is that I do not see `user` field on `Profile` model so you should anyway get 404

Comment: I think I am going around in circles and getting more confused.
`Class Profile(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                related_name='prof_user',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

is the user field in the profile model. It points to the User model

Comment: Sorry for confusion - I didn't noticed `user` field on `Profile`. It's ok, but `clinic` is still a queryset which is weird because you filtering by `pk` so suppos to have a single record returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=Clinic.objects.get(pk=clinic_id).practitioner)
mods = profile[0].mods.all() if profile else []
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to step out for half an hour. I'll try this when I get home again

Answer (score 0):

I believe your view needs to look something like:

```
clinic = clinic.objects.get(pk=clinic_id)
profile = profile.objects.get(clinic.practitioner)
mods = mods.objects.filter(pk__in=profile.mods.values_list('pk'))
```

Comment: `clinic = Clinic.objects.get(pk=clinic_id)`
`profile = the profile of the clinic.practitioner`
`mods = mods.objects.filter(pk__in=profile.mods.values_list('pk'))`

I think I'm getting closer. What I need now is to get the user referred to in Clinic.practitioner

Comment: Could you add some more explanation to help both the OP and others? A code-only explanation can be cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

```
clinic = Clinic.objects.get(clinic_id)
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
mods = profile.mods.filter(name__startswith=clinic.pk)
```

but not that if the clinic_id is 1
the mods starting with 10,11,111 etc will also be selected unless you have a particular way of entering modality name.

Comment: I realised I dont actually want the profile of the session user. 
What I want in the profile line is the profile of the clinic.practitioner